# Java: Passing multiple values to handlebar template

Tags: java, handlebars.java

I am using handlebar templates to prepare email content dynamically before sending over it.

It's straightforward to pass just one value. For example:

`What's up {{this}}` template workes fine with `template.apply(firstName)`.

Tried changing the template to `What's up {{this}}, {{this}}` and try to fill in by `template.apply(lastName);` and `template.apply(firstName);`.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

pass a map as parameter.

template.hbs

```
What's up {{firstName}}, {{lastName}}
```

controll.java

```
template.apply(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
    {
        put("firstName", "Himanshu");
        put("lastName", "Yadav");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to refer to the variables you set on the `this` object by their name.

```
What's up {{firstName}}, {{lastName}}
```

Comment: `handleBar` doesn't work that way. Would you mind elaborating your reply little bit?

Comment: is handlebars.java something different from handlebars.js?